# App not drawing

Tags: android

I have my class:

```
public class CustomDrawableView extends View{

    private ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable;

    public CustomDrawableView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
        shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.GREEN);
        shapeDrawable.setBounds(20,20,20,20);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        shapeDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }

}
```

Then in the main activity I have this code in the oncreate function:

```
private CustomDrawableView customDrawableView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    customDrawableView = new CustomDrawableView(this);
    setContentView(customDrawableView);
}
```

For some reason, it doesn't draw though. I have my CustomDrawableView class which I have created an instance of in the oncreate method in mainactiviy. I have set the content view to the instance of my class too.

Also, is this a good way to create graphics for a game I want to make. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to call super.onDraw() at the beginning of onDraw()?

Answer (score 0):

Check this call:

```
shapeDrawable.setBounds(20,20,20,20);
```

the parameters are `left, top, right, bottom`, so it effectively sets the size of the drawable to 0.